# Is it safe to exclude the Sorbet errors.txt from your git repo?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

`errors.txt` tends to have a lot of changes when you run `srb rbi update`, and I've seen the Sorbet developers mention before that it's not really meant for anything other than debugging.

So, is it safe to ignore the `errors.txt` file? Will doing so cause any negative effects?

Comment: What’s in it? Is it a log file?

Comment: it looks like this, it's just a list of errors: https://github.com/connorshea/VideoGameList/blob/f3e0178a0c10c5d03ac7d0ae0f5e62383a2cdbc9/sorbet/rbi/hidden-definitions/errors.txt

Comment: It does look like it should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to be ignored. As you mention, it's used to debug when things go wrong.